# Wordpress hook attachment_fields_to_save doesn't effect attachment data on file upload

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, filter, hook, attachment

I'm trying to find out where Wordpress initially sets the post title of an attachment.

After stumbling through the source I found a hook named [attachment_fields_to_save](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/attachment_fields_to_save) which - according to the documentation - "provides default values to the post_title". Seems to be the right spot, BUT...

For some reason I can't use this hook to alter the attachment data by adding a filter function like this:

```
function tt_use_filter($post, $attachment) {
    $post['post_title'] = 'Nasenbär';
    return $post;
}
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_save', 'tt_use_filter', 10, 2);
```

I tried several things to make this work:

- created (and activated) a plugin
- edited the theme's functions.php
- increased the priority parameter
- hacked the core function [image_attachment_fields_to_save](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_attachment_fields_to_save/)
- even downgraded from 4.0 to 3.9

What am I missing here?

**To save your time:** I'm not interested in any workaround since I know how to accomplish custom default values. I literally want to know why the hook `attachment_fields_to_save` shows no effect on a file upload when using the code above.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is pretty easy: `attachment_fields_to_save` isn't called on a file upload!

How did I find out? After googling the subject "Wordpress debugging" I came across [this blogpost](http://westi.wordpress.com/2012/01/28/tracing-things-back-to-where-they-came-from/) that mentions the veeery useful Wordpress function [wp_debug_backtrace_summary](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_debug_backtrace_summary/). You can use this gem to backtrace every function call that happend until the execution of `wp_debug_backtrace_summary` itself.

On further notice: Using that debug tool I found the function that sets the post title initially on a file upload with ease. It's [media_handle_upload](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload).